# SSIS (Version 13) ODBC Source component

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, visual-studio-2015

Where I can find ODBC Source component in SSIS ver 13 (VS 2015)??

This is ODBC Source in SSIS ver 11:

[image]

But I can't find it in new VS :(:( :

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there are not released SSDT BI for VS2015 yet, only some preview, so it's probably not fully supported. Use VS2013, or don't use SSIS at all, it's crap :-/

Comment: "or don't use SSIS at all, it's crap" :):)

Comment: I am manualy recreated this package in VS2015 and used ADO NET Source with ODBC Provider.

Answer (score 0):

I am manualy recreated this package in VS2015 and used "ADO NET Source" with "ODBC Provider". Everything work fine.